# ¿Por qué escribimos "etcétera" junto?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, latín

La voz *[etcétera](https://dle.rae.es/?id=H3QU4GM)* y su abreviación *etc.* provienen, según el diccionario:

> Del lat. *et cetĕra* 'y lo demás'.

De hecho, este latinismo se usaba separado allá por el siglo XIV:

> *Interrogados del X.º articulo, si algunos heredan non deuidament heredades o muebles de los muertos, non seyendo parientes, et cetera. Dizen que non herid y a ninguno en la dicta villa qui herede en tal manera.*
>
> Anónimo, "Libro de monedaje de Tudela", 1353 (España).

Incluso también con la *et* adaptada al castellano y con tilde en *cétera*:

> *E mandamos que los cavalleros que tovieren las maiores casas pobladas con mugeres e con fijos, e los que no tovieren mugeres con la compaña que ovieren, desde ocho días antes de Navidad fasta ocho días después de Cincuesma, e tovieren cavallos e armas, el cavallo de treinta maravedís arriba, e escudo e lanza e loriga e brafineras e perpunte e capiello de fierro e espada, que no peche, e cétera*.
>
> Anónimo, "El consejo real sentencia a favor de los pecheros abulenses", 1389 (España).

En el siglo XVI incluso se encuentran algunos textos con "y cétera":

> *Y que por quanto las denominaciones de las dignidades van continuadas en proporción arithmética 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, y cétera [...].*
>
> Pedro Núñez, "Libro de Álgebra en Aritmética y Geometría", 1567 (España).

Sin embargo, la forma que ha prevalecido es la que une ambas palabras en una sola, manteniendo el *et* del latín original. ¿Qué fue lo que ocasionó esta unión? ¿Cuándo tuvo lugar?

Comment: Nota: en catalán (etcètera), gallego (etcétera) y italiano (eccetera) también se deletrea como una palabra (pero no en francés (et cétéra) o portugués (et cetera), y rumano usa ambos ortografías).

Comment: En inglés también se puede escribir como una palabra, aunque todavía se aceptan separadas.

Comment: Parece simple ahorro de espacio. Es una palabra demasiado frecuente en listas indefinidas. El ahorro de letras es hoy dia valorado en mensajería móvil, imagínate antes de la imprenta, cuando se copiaba en piel de cordero.

Answer (score 2):

No hay que olvidar que las lenguas romances básicamente es latín vulgar vulgarizado, valga la redundancia. Latín vulgar mal hablado, y mal escrito, donde los errores al final se convierten en norma.

En consecuencia, no tiene nada de extraño que dos palabras latinas que se usen con frecuencia juntas, al cabo de siglos deriven en una sola, por ahorro de espacio al escribir, como se comenta, o de tiempo al hablar, o por la tendencia a escribir lo que crees escuchar.

Al hablar rápido, las pausas entre palabras son casi imperceptibles, y no tienen nada de extraño que quién supiera escribir algo, pero no fuera muy ducho en latín, escuchara por ejemplo *vice versa* y acabara escribiendo  «viceversa» y, que con el tiempo, esto se acabara admitiendo como una palabra correcta, pero en español.

Y del mismo modo acabamos usando «adlátere» y «exprofeso» en lugar de *ad latere* y *ex professo*, por ejemplo.

Unir palabras se ha hecho siempre, y con frecuencia. Hoy decimos «duodécimo» porque en latín se decía  *duodecim*, que se forma evidentemente por juntar *duo decem*. Y hoy decimos «caligrafía» que significa «hermosa escritura» porque viene de dos palabras separadas en indoeuropeo *kalós* y  *gráphō*, que los griegos empleaban por separado (κάλλος, , *kallós* y γράφειν, *graphein*) o ya juntas  (καλλιγραφία, *kalligraphía*), y de ahí al latín y al español casi sin cambios.

Solo hay que pensar  un poco en nuestro vocabulario actual para darnos cuenta que muchas palabras son palabras compuestas donde se reconocen fácilmente prefijos o sufijos con raíz latina o griega, pero indagas un poco en la etimología de otras palabras que no parecen términos compuestos y algunas en realidad también lo eran.